# Возникает ошибка при использовании startActivity()

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть код:

```
package com.codex.touchface;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Random;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Intent activity_splash1;
    public TextView textDown;
    public int get_ban;
    public int ban;
    public int signup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        textDown = findViewById(R.id.textDown);
        Random random = new Random();
        int text_downRandom = random.nextInt(4);
        if (text_downRandom == 1){
            textDown.setText("#общайся");
        }
        if (text_downRandom == 2){
            textDown.setText("#обсуждай");
        }
        if (text_downRandom == 3){
            textDown.setText("#продавай");
        }
        if (text_downRandom == 4){
            textDown.setText("#покупай");
        }
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser cUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (cUser != null) {
            final String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            myRef.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        UserGet userGet = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserGet.class);
                        get_ban = userGet.getBan();
                    }
                    if (get_ban == 0) {
                        ban = 2;
                    } else {
                        ban = 1;
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            signup = 1;
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            if (ban == 2){
                activity_splash1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
            }
            if (ban == 1){
                activity_splash1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ban.class);
            }
            if (signup == 1){
                activity_splash1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignIn.class);
            }
            startActivity(activity_splash1);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }, 1000);
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения происходит ошибка :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codex.touchface, PID: 9126
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1682)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5216)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
        at com.codex.touchface.SplashActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$SplashActivity(SplashActivity.java:88)
        at com.codex.touchface.-$$Lambda$SplashActivity$e5v8bUh7wXNBSzQqMlH-8kdc1jQ.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9126 SIG: 9
```

Android Studio указывает на `startActivity(activity_splash1);`

Можете помочь пожалуйста. Не могу разобраться с этой ошибкой уже более месяца.

Answer (score 0):

Intent не имеет никакого присвоения, потому что скорее всего никакой из последних условий If не выполняется. Отлогируй все случаи и поймешь какой кусок не работает